# How can I store a pdf in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, insert, blob

I have to store .pdf files in a table.

I have a table, `state`, with columns:

```
id_state,
name,
pdffile (bytea)
```

I want to store the pdf files in the pdffile column.

How can I do this?

Comment: ... and you're sure you don't want to store it in a file system location and have that location stored in the database (just for clarification and not for flame wars, just trying to ensure bases are covered)?

Comment: Which programming language do you use? @swasheck: there are perfectly valid reasons to store this kind of things in a database. As with everything it has its advantages and disadvantages (I personally think it has more advantages than disadvantages).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I know. As I said, I was just ensuring that this was the best course of action for OP's use case.

Answer (score 5):

First, I store PDF's in the db as bytea's.  They are easier to manage than large objects and you really dont get very much out of the streaming API (now, streaming video, that should go into lobs).  The one real problem with doing this is that it takes extra memory to unescape the data when it comes back to the database and you really can't stream it effectively.

The key thing is that you have to unescape the data when it comes back.  libpq provides functions for that as do other programming languages.  A few (like Perl) provide db drivers which automatically handle these cases.

You are on to the right structure here.  Store it as a bytea and unescape it on retrieval.

Comment: This is a very abbreviated list of downfalls. It's not just streaming. It's the backend session stays tied while it's sending the file down to libpq as part of the resultset. Also, whatever other data is left on the row is likely also not ready to display until the PDF transfers. Parallel operations like https pipelining on pdf? You'll now have to tie up the database with one session per PDF.

Comment: But those are very use-specific downfalls.  They don't apply, for example, where you are storing data for specific reasons where those are not applicable.  For example wanting to store PDFs actually sent to a customer for tracking purposes.  There are OLTP reasons why one might want to do so in an OLTP system.

Answer (score 4):

## Don't store PDFs in the database

There are no database features that can edit or process a PDF. Storing them is likely to lock up your db-session for extended periods. There is absolutely no reason whatsoever to do this. PostgreSQL is not a filesystem, it's a database.

Comment: I disagree with you.  PDFs are just values and being able to back up pdfs attached to database entities in the same backup is a good reason you might want to.

Comment: @ChrisTravers They're not just values: they're files. You can't seek through a value. You can always seek through a file. A value is a piece of data. A file, especially a pdf file, is an input for an external program. A database does not manage the display, a PDF encompasses display. Your RDBMS is not a backup management tool. You can easily back up the database and the filesystem at the same time.

Comment: If you want to seek, lobs in Postgres give you that.  Usually it is not what you want in a db however.

Comment: Lobs are useful, so is bytea. But, not for PDFs. This is an absolutely horrible idea. There are plenty of really good applications of both technologies. Need to store rasters in a database -- lobs are great for that.

Comment: So have an accounting system.  Want to track invoice pdfs as sent out, and guarantee that these are properly tracked to the transactions for auditing reasons.  Why not store them in PostgreSQL.  All we need to do is store them, retrieve them, and most importantly back up and restore them with the rest of the data?  I.e. they are *values* for auditing purposes.

Comment: No reason whatsoever is a dangerous statement and *almost always* wrong.

Comment: I'm not saying that it won't work. It will. However, those benefits are not free the costs are abnormally high. Every time you update that row inside the database, you have to rewrite out the pdf. Every time you update the row, the PDF has to get wal-logged and shipped out for replication. It's just a really bad idea. There are better ways to keep file systems backed up and in sync than this. The costs are just too high.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this I have used the library `lipq`. It's the C API for postgresql.

```
const char *paramValues[2];
paramValues[0] = &your_id;
paramValues[1] = &binaryContentOfPdfFile;

res = PQexecParams(pConnection, "insert into my_table (id_state, pdffile)
VALUES ($1, $2);",
        2,       /* params */
        NULL,    /* let the backend deduce param type */
        paramValues,
        NULL,    /* don't need param lengths since text */
        NULL,    /* default to all text params */
        0);
```

[Here is the postgresql mailing list thread I took the code from.](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/ae830e6c05060309182201f85b@mail.gmail.com)

I guess it would be something not so different with other API like `pyODBC` or `psqlODBC`. It depends on the library you have chosen. **You didn't say which API you use**.

However: you should also consider storing only the URI/URL to the pdf file in your database.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way store PDF file in postgresql is via *large object*. You should have a table field of type `OID`. The create a large object with your PDF and then store the large object `OID` in the table.

Be careful with postgresql 9, since large object rights where defined. If you want to share access to the large object to many different postgresql users, you have to `GRANT` them the `SELECT` right. Please note that you cannot `GRANT` the `DELETE` right, so the owner is the one that must delete the object.

Moreover, special care should be done for maintaining storage: whenever you delete a large object, and you remove the OID from the table, the large object storage is not freed. You should run a command from contrib package, called `vacuumlo`, anche then the normal `vacuumdb`.